# regexp_replace POSTGRESQL

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have problem with regex.

I want to search text like this `' A ' - (space, BIG SINGLE CHAR and SPACE)`

```
SELECT regexp_replace(' A Text B Text C Text a Text', '(([ ]{1}[A-Z]{1,1}[ ]{1}))', ' \1 ', 'g')
```

So all is ok, but I want to replace this single big char for small char.

```
SELECT regexp_replace(' A Text B Text C Text a Text', '(([ ]{1}[A-Z]{1,1}[ ]{1}))', lower(' \1 '), 'g')
```

do not work.

How can I use function in this matched `\1`, for example `lower()` to get result

`a Text b Text c Text a Text` ?

Thanks.

Comment: could you post the expected output?

Comment: ' a Text b Text c Text a Text'

replace A B and C for lower case

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex

`((^|\s)[A-Z]\s)`

see the example of how it works http://regex101.com/r/mK4dR9/2

Comment: Ok. But how to replace A (upper case) for a (lower case) ?

Answer (score 0):

First, some notes about your regexp:

- `[ ]` is the same as  (single space) - single characters do not need brackets
- `{1}` and `{1,1}` is obsolete, this is the default behavior (no quantifier means exactly one time)

Let's clarify: `lower(' \1 ')` is evaluated to `' \1 '` **before** you call `regexp_replace`. Because that, there is no difference between your queries.

You can't achieve what you want with `regexp_replace` - you need something like `regexp_replace_eval` (to transform your replacements with custom functions), but this is not available in PostgreSQL.

The most you can do, is to split up your original string & replace in the split-parts:

```
select substring(string_agg(lower(substring(p for :length)) || substring(p from :length + 1), '') from :length + 1)
from regexp_split_to_table(repeat(' ', :length) || :input, '(?=' || :pattern || ')') p

-- in your case

select substring(string_agg(lower(substring(p for 3)) || substring(p from 4), '') from 4)
from regexp_split_to_table('   ' || ' A Text B Text C Text a Text', '(?= [A-Z] )') p
```

But **note**: this will only work with fixed-length regexp patterns.